# Displaying uploaded files

Tags: views, javascript

Preface -- I'm a newbie with drupal and have watched too many youtube flicks on jCarousel and slideshows.  So totally confused.

My question:
I've created a web form in drupal 7 and would like to do a jCarousel of all the images that have been uploaded via the web form.  Is there a way to point to a directory and have the jCarousel load the image files.  I tried creating a view with show files, but it didn't load the image files.

I'm trying to do this without css or javascript.  I don't pantheon service provider will let me add javascript (I think).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you created the view what was the FORMAT that you had choosen? Was it  jCarousel?

Comment: Yeah, I was using jCarousel.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to display the image file in the jCarousel.  In a view add the file:Name field and set the style settings to HTML and add the image source hmtl  tag to rewrite results.  Example: